# How to put multiple Id into get parameters method

Tags: apex, visualforce

I want to display a table in pdf. I am passing multiple id into the Visualforce page from apex class but each time the id is overridden and the last id is passed into the VF page. 
Below are the two approaches I am using. Please give the correct way to pass multiple ids

First approach

```
for(Case cs : caseList)
        {
            pagePdf.getParameters().put('id'+count , cs.Id);
            count ++;
            System.debug('Count'+count );
            System.debug('Id ='+cs.Id);
        }
```

Second approach

```
Set<Id> caseIds = new Set<Id>();
for (Case curCase : caseList) {
    caseIds.add(curCase.Id);
}
pagePdf.getParameters().put('ids', String.join(new List<Id>(caseIds),','));
```

Comment: you should also add the `nooverride` parameter that's equal to `1` I believe

Comment: @Novarg If i add nooverride parameter in put method then how i can pass the id to the vf page.

Comment: for (Case curCase : caseList) {
                System.debug(curcase.Id);
              
                         pagePdf = new PageReference('/apex/DeskAuditReport?&id='+curCase.Id+ '&nooverride=true'); 

               
                
              
            }

Comment: Still it is overiding and displaying records of last id

Comment: try putting `nooverride=1`, not true

Comment: Still, it is overriding the id.